# GetEnvironmentVariableW and GetEnvironmentStringsW returns different values

Tags: c++, windows, environment-variables, mingw, msys2

I'm developing an UTF-8 API which should transparently work independent of the OS.

For that I'm replacing `getenv` by `GetEnvironmentVariableW` and the `char** env` passed to `main` by `GetEnvironmentStringsW`.

To make sure everything is correct I iterate over the `env` array and check each value against `GetEnvironmentVariableW` to make sure they match.

This works everywhere but with MinGW/MSYS where it fails for the env variable `temp` where `getenv = C:\msys64\tmp` and `GetEnvironmentStringsW` returns `C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1`

I verified the value using `c:\msys64\usr\bin\env MSYSTEM=MINGW32 c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash -l -c "echo $temp"` (similar how the build/test is run) and there it returns `C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1`.

So it seems `GetEnvironmentVariableW` returns a different/wrong value.

How is this possible? Can I avoid this?

Code of the test is:

```
for(char** e = env; *e != 0; e++)
{
    const char* key_begin = *e;
    const char* key_end = strchr(key_begin, '=');
    std::string key = std::string(key_begin, key_end);
    std::string value = key_end + 1;
    const char* env_value = boost::nowide::getenv(key.c_str());
    TEST_EQ(env_value, value);
}
```

where the getenv function is (reduced without error checking etc):

```
char* getenv(const char* key)
{
    static const size_t buf_size = 64;
    wchar_t buf[buf_size];
    GetEnvironmentVariableW(widen(key), buf, buf_size);
    return narrow(buf);
}
```

Edit: I was able to reproduce this with the following minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const size_t buf_size = 4000;
    char buf[buf_size];
    GetEnvironmentVariable("temp", buf, buf_size);
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (e.g. in MSVC) and run with `temp=Foobar ./a.out` in e.g. Git bash on Windows it prints `C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp` not `Foobar`. In GetEnvironmentStrings the value is correct

Comment: Check again, I just tried that experiment, in `GetEnvironmentStrings` there are 2 variables, `temp` and `TEMP`, and `GetEnvironmentVariable` is case insensitive, so it returns whatever is first in the list.

Comment: Spot on! From my CI:
`Checking TEMP=C:\msys64\tmp --> getenv: C:\msys64\tmp` and `Checking temp=C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1 --> getenv: C:\msys64\tmp`